# Is there standard terminology/notation for the "prefix" of a word?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, computer-science, monoid, combinatorics-on-words

Given a word like $abbbaaaba$, we can take (say) the first three letters. We might write $$\mathrm{foo}_3(abbbaaaba) = abb,$$ or something like that. Is there any standard terminology or notation here?

Comment: the term is cohomology

Comment: What about "prefix of length 3"?

Comment: [Prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring#Prefix) seems quite common.

Comment: @mathworker21: huh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**prefix (of length $3$)** is pretty logical, but I am finding a lot of hits for the second obvious thing that came to mind:

**initial segment (of length $3$)**

E.g. see [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=TJfm2GJPXf8C&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq=%22initial%20segment%22&source=bl&ots=A1ELNiaP0S&sig=aWqUWaxrvh9rLFXq7XSWwcK_EWk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjx_Zi74N3SAhWI6SYKHdHsBaMQ6AEIOjAF#v=onepage&q=%22initial%20segment%22&f=false), and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_triangle), and [this](http://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/s-t-strings-say-s-initial-segment-t-nonempty-string-u-t-su-su-string-s-followed-string-u-e-q17809422).